# PredictionIO : pio train fails with stack overflow error

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, predictionio

I'm trying to build a recommendation engine using predictionIO's similar product template. I modified the template to recommend user's instead of items by following this [article](https://predictionio.apache.org/templates/similarproduct/recommended-user/). Now if I train my model for the first time by importing the sample data provided it works successfully.

If I add a couple of more entries to the event server and if I try to train my model again by using command `pio train`, I'm getting the following error :

```
[WARN] [LAPACK] Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
[WARN] [LAPACK] Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$WeakClassKey.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:2451)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:336)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.writeObject(List.scala:468)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.writeObject(List.scala:468)
```

How does pio train works? Do I need to delete the previously trained model and train again?

Can someone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
From my understanding this is due to lack of resources from a hardware perspective. (Probably you need more CPUs or RAM).

What you can do is reduce the number of iterations. (WARNING: This will most probably reduce the accuracy of your output).

To do this, edit your engine.json file. There you can find a value called "numIterations".
Decrease that value.
I initially halved the value (from 10 to 5), just to make sure it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem and found the solution in the following article.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-an-recommendation-engine-with-apache-prediction-io-ml-server-aed0319e0d8

Decrease the number of iterations in engine.json and rebuild the app before training.

`"numIterations": 5,`